# How to refresh table after button click in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table generated after ajax call success.When i re select the options and click on the button data added to existing table only.Here i want to refresh the table with updated table.Unable to set the the refresh functionality.For any help Thanks in advance.

```
function viewAttendanceSheet() {
    var date = $("#datepicker").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "attendanceList",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            "date": date
        },
        success: function(data, status) {
            alert(status);
            alert(JSON.stringify(data.length));
            var res = String(JSON.stringify(data)).split(",");
            if (data.length == 0) {
                newRowContent = ("<tr>NOTHING TO DISPALY...</tr>");
                $("#ajaxViewAttendanceSheet").append(newRowContent);
            } else {
                $("#attendanceViewTableHead").css("display", "block");
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    if (value.status == "Absent") {
                        newRowContent = ("<tr><td>" + value.studentName + "</td><td style=color:red;>" + value.status + "**</td></tr>");
                    } else {
                        newRowContent = ("<tr><td>" + value.studentName + "</td><td style=color:green;>" + value.status + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                    $("#ajaxViewAttendanceSheet").append(newRowContent);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i will suggest you to empty the table before appending any new data via calling `$("#ajaxViewAttendanceSheet").empty();` just after your `alert(JSON.stringify(data.length));` statement.

Comment: This is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588260/how-to-remove-an-appended-element-with-jquery-and-why-bind-or-live-is-causing-el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function viewAttendanceSheet() {
        var date = $("#datepicker").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "attendanceList",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "date": date
            },
            success: function(data, status) {
                $("#ajaxViewAttendanceSheet").html('');
                var res = String(JSON.stringify(data)).split(",");
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    newRowContent = ("<tr>NOTHING TO DISPALY...</tr>");
                    $("#ajaxViewAttendanceSheet").append(newRowContent);
                } else {
                    $("#attendanceViewTableHead").css("display", "block");
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        if (value.status == "Absent") {
                            newRowContent = ("<tr><td>" + value.studentName + "</td><td style=color:red;>" + value.status + "**</td></tr>");
                        } else {
                            newRowContent = ("<tr><td>" + value.studentName + "</td><td style=color:green;>" + value.status + "</td></tr>");
                        }
                        $("#ajaxViewAttendanceSheet").append(newRowContent);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

You should reset the html of the table each time ajax load successfully by: $("#ajaxViewAttendanceSheet").html('');

Comment: Why this answer is getting down votes.is there any drawback with using this solution

Comment: I think maybe other people thought I just copy and paste your code above.

But actually I made a fix inside the code. I'd better explain my fix next time :)

Comment: yah.yopu added solution in my code.Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Complicated answers for a simple question.

Call this method after this line  `var res = String(JSON.stringify(data)).split(",");` to clear out the elements and values in those elements.

```
  $("#ajaxViewAttendanceSheet").empty();
```

Use the JQuery method `empty()`

https://api.jquery.com/empty/